# Why do I have to cast in this Kotlin code?

Tags: kotlin, generics

```
interface Foo<T: Bar> {
    fun example(bar: T)
}

interface Bar

class Bar1 : Bar

class Bar2 : Bar

class FooEx1 : Foo<Bar1> {
    override fun example(bar: Bar1) { }
}

class FooEx2 : Foo<Bar2> {
    override fun example(bar: Bar2) { }
}

// Won't compile
// Even though FooEx1 and FooEx2 *are* Foo<Bar>
class ExampleDoesntCompile {
    val collection = mutableListOf<Foo<Bar>>().apply {
        this.add(FooEx1())
        this.add(FooEx2())
    }
}

// Will compile
// But have to cast FooEx1 and FooEx2 to Foo<Bar>
class ExampleDoesCompileButRequiresCast {
    val collection = mutableListOf<Foo<Bar>>().apply {
        this.add(FooEx1() as Foo<Bar>)
        this.add(FooEx2() as Foo<Bar>)
    }
}
```

So, I could for instance, state that Foo's parameterized type is `out`, but then I get a compile error for the function `example`:

```
interface Foo<out T: Bar> {
    fun example(bar: T)
}
```

Error: `Type parameter T is declared as 'out' but occurs in 'in' position in type T`

Comment: A`Foo<Bar1>` is **not** a `Foo<Bar>`, see this related question (Java): [Is List<Dog> a subclass of List<Animal>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-are-java-generics-not-implicitly-po?rq=1)

Comment: So it'll crash at run time with the cast?

Comment: It won't crash when you cast it because generic types cannot be checked. It will crash if you retrieve something from this list and try to call `example()` on it by passing a `Bar` to it that the implementation is not equipped to handle. https://pl.kotl.in/h3lGqgowk

Comment: This is what the compiler errors are trying to protect you from when you improperly handle variance/invariance. Your `FooEx1` is a limited implementation of `Foo` that can only handle a specific type of `Bar`. If you could just put it in a list of `Foo<Bar>`, then the compiler would be allowing you to ignore your own generic type restrictions and opening you up to bugs that are hard to track down.

Comment: Sort of makes sense, always makes my brain hurt though. I'm sure I never had these issues when dealing with C# generics.

Comment: Maybe just because contravariant classes aren't as common as covariant/invariant ones? Covariance works like what you were expecting above. C# also has covariance and contravariance, also specified with `out` and `in`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because generic types in Java / Kotlin are invariant by default. [variance](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#variance)

```
interface Foo<out T: Bar>
```

If you can't make it covariant, then make the list items covariant

```
val collection = mutableListOf<Foo<out Bar>>().apply {
    this.add(FooEx1())
    this.add(FooEx2())
}

 //or  val collection = mutableListOf(FooEx1(), FooEx2())
```

Comment: Sure, but that forces my functions on the Foo interface to produce Bar, not consume it, which isn't what I want :-(

Comment: Granted, I didn't state that in the OP. I'll update it now

Comment: Plus, I don't think you need to update the mutable list to state `out`, just declaring it on the interface is enough.

Comment: @ThomasCook remove `out` from interface and add it to type in list

Comment: @ThomasCook I think you are confused with covariance and contravariance, read this https://proandroiddev.com/understanding-generics-and-variance-in-kotlin-714c14564c47 Comparator<Animal> is subclass of Comparator<Bird>, because you can compare any animal by size or any property Animal exhibits **but Comparator<Bird> is not necessarily a Comparator<Animal>** because you may want to compare them by feathers which isn't even a property of Animal, so you cannot compare Insects with Comparator<Bird>.

Comment: But note that if you use `Foo<out Bar>` you'll find you can't actually call `example`...

Answer (score 0):

> So it'll crash at run time with the cast?

Here is example code that would crash:

```
val foo: Foo<Bar> = collection[0]
foo.example(Bar2())
```

So if you could create `collection` without a cast as in your `ExampleDoesntCompile`, you'd get code without any casts which throws a `ClassCastExcepion`.

This also shows why the interface can't be declared with `out`:

```
val foo: Foo<Bar> = FooEx1() // out would make this legal
foo.example(Bar2())
```

It would make sense to declare your interface with `in`, but this would mean a `Foo<Bar>` is a `Foo<Bar1>` and a `Foo<Bar2>`, not vice versa, so still wouldn't let you put `FooEx1`/`2` into a collection of `Foo<Bar>`s.